# Change datatype without changing "not null" constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I created table "A" with datatype VARCHAR2(3000) with "Not null" constraint. Table "A" has one column "someColumn" which is as primary key. As below:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  "someColumn"  VARCHAR2(3000)  NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE A
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_A PRIMARY KEY (
  "someColumn"
)
```

Now I want change datatype from VARCHAR2(3000) to VARCHAR2(4000) but I don't want change constraint. So I used:

```
ALTER TABLE A
MODIFY
(
  "someColumn" VARCHAR2(4000)
)
```

It worked and now I have ddl like below:

```
PROMPT CREATE TABLE a
CREATE TABLE a (
  "someColumn" VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL
)
/

PROMPT ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT pk_a PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE a
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_a PRIMARY KEY (
    "someColumn"
  )
/
```

Then I used code as below:

```
ALTER TABLE A
MODIFY
(
  "someColumn" VARCHAR2(3000) NULL
)
```

I got message "Alter table, executed..." but when I checked ddl again - I have "Not null" constraint still and new datatype (4000).
It's Oracle error?
To be sure that I don't have any cache in my "SQLTools" I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'A'
```

**Answer:
The change to NULLABLE fails but silently, so I see no error message.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a column that is *primary key* you may change the length, but you can't do it `nullable` (because it is a `PK` which can't be `NULL`).

**Initial state 3000 length NOT NULL**

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, NULLABLE from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'A'; 
COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_LENGTH N
------------------------------ ----------- -
someColumn                            3000 N
```

**Change length to 4000 - OK**

```
ALTER TABLE A
MODIFY
(
  "someColumn" VARCHAR2(4000)
)
;

select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, NULLABLE from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'A'; 
COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_LENGTH N
------------------------------ ----------- -
someColumn                            4000 N
```

**Change length to 3000 - OK**

**make it nullable - fails SILENTLY as PK can't be nullable**

```
ALTER TABLE A
MODIFY
(
  "someColumn" VARCHAR2(3000) NULL
);

select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, NULLABLE from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'A'; 

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_LENGTH N
------------------------------ ----------- -
someColumn                            3000 N
```

If you wan't to see a error message  - split the change in two (change length *and* set nullable).

The first one will pass, the second will explicitely fail.

```
ALTER TABLE A
MODIFY
(
  "someColumn"   VARCHAR2(3000)
);

ALTER TABLE A
MODIFY
(
  "someColumn"   NULL
);

ORA-01451: column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to NULL
```

Comment: I know that PK can't be NULL but I got message "Alter table, executed...". Why?

Comment: Correct, the change to `NULLABLE` fails but *silently*, so you see no error message. You may live with it or open an SR;)

Comment: So it's Oracle error because when I tried modify dataType and I added "Not null" constraint - I got ORA-01442 Error Message. They are not consistent.